# Singleton WorkingQueue show in WPF View

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, layer

in my actual project I have a layered application with wpf, mvvm, a logic and model layer. Main task of this app is to convert my videos. So I have implemented a singleton working queue, with a list of movies. Movie is a class, with progress and state and so on...

One big problem I have is, that I don't know how to show this working queue in the view. Now I do it this way: I set every second (with a timer) my working queue list to a observablecollection in my viewmodel. That is not very beautiful, because every second my selcted row, will be grey, because I set the complete list.

Can you think of a better solution, I'm sure there is one?

Thank you,
Dominik

Comment: Why is this queue a singleton?

Comment: I thought, it is better for this task than a normal class, but now I think, a normal class is better. In my business logic, I have a processor class, which processes the file (get informations -> compressing -> move to location) and I think, every process class must have a working queue. It's better this way I think.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have an ObservableCollection with all the jobs. If you add a job to the ObservableCollection you also add this job to the working queue. When the job is done, it can be removed from the Observable Collection. Do this is a kind of Finished event.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is, that I have to refresh the process. I could make an event, which fires on progress change and make a RaisePropertyChanged.

Comment: Yes - that's similar to a Finished event.